# How can I pass a instance method in Perl?

Tags: perl

```
sub method_of_class_A {
    B->new(back => a_specific_method_of_class_A)->run;
}
```

I want to pass current `A` instance `a`'s `a_specific_method_of_class_A` to `B`'s instance `b` so that `b` can `goto` `a`'s `a_specific_method_of_class_A`

as if `a->a_specific_method_of_class_A` is called directly so that the stack doesn't accumulate.

How to do this kind of job in Perl?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`can`](http://p3rl.org/UNIVERSAL) method.

Comment: Actually, this is pretty much what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking what I think you're asking, you probably have to pass a closure:

```
sub method_of_class_A {
    my $self = shift;
    return B->new( 
          back => sub { $self->a_specific_method_of_class_A(); } 
        )->run;
}
```

and I think that's what you need because you do not seem to be passing an instance of `$a` to B.

If you need this a lot, you could assign it as a field in the object:

```
back =>  $self->{invoke_method_closure} 
     ||= sub { $self->a_specific_method_of_class_A(); }
```

I'm not really sure how either of these ideas helps with the criteria "that the stack doesn't accumulate", because I'm not really sure what this criteria entails. The `goto` call will simply avoid adding *1* level to the stack. However, if you look at that block, you'll see what you're going to. And you'll jump to a instruction to invoke the method in a normal way. So that level that you "saved" is used anyway.

`goto`s are better not to try to prematurely optimize method invocation but to pass the stack to another handler with some wrapping behavior. So it works well enough in `import` methods which delegate to `Exporter`'s basic behavior, or `AUTOLOAD` subs which try to figure out what the caller wants to do and then invoke the proper code with the passed arguments.

Comment: could you illustrate your goto point with code? I don't understand what you are arguing for or against

Comment: Using //= is a better choice in this case